# 'Way to success' or 'road to success'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I would like to start a blog and title it 'On the Way to Success'. I know that there is a term 'road to success'. I wonder if 'On the Way to Success' is a correctly written phrase, and what would be a meaning of it?

Comment: Note usage frequency in Google Books: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+way++to+success%2Cthe+road+to+success&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20way%20to%20success%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20road%20to%20success%3B%2Cc0

Comment: As a kid I lived in a house along "Cardwell Way"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both have the same meaning. You should be fine with either of them.

However, if you're trying to make a decision between the two, one way to proceed is that you might consider the following two concepts and whether you wish to emphasize them equally in your blog, or one more than the other.

1. Methods and steps to be successful (kind of like a "how to" blog)
2. Journeys to success, e.g., testimonials or inspiring stories of how people became successful

The [Oxford english dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/way) gives both these as valid definitions of "way":

> A method, style, or manner of doing something.
>
> ‘there are two ways of approaching this problem’

and

> A road, track, path, or street for traveling along.
>
> in place names ‘No. 3, Church Way’

so it captures both meanings. So it may be good to use "way" if your blog might contain posts of both types, especially if they have equal weight.

On the other hand, "road" may give readers or potential readers the feeling (rightly or wrongly) that the blog leans more towards discussing journeys/paths to success.

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer! I like this disambiguation actually. I would like to cover both meanings :)

Comment: @Lukasz Glad to have helped. So you'll probably use "way" rather than "road"?

Comment: Yes :) My blog will be describing my humble way from a corporate rat to an entrepreneur. With all the mistakes, lessons on the way. Again, 'on the way'.

Comment: That's great! Feel free to let us know the blog URL in a comment when ready :-)

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same meaning, its just a thing that you have used way to success instead of road to success.

Answer (score -1):

Both expressions are correct, but ***the road to..*** appears to be more idiomatic:

***[the road to (something )](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/the-road-to-something)***

> a process or series of events that will achieve something or have a particular result
>
> - The road to success is not always an easy one.
>
> on the road to recovery/success etc.
>
> - After weeks of illness he is finally on the road to recovery.
> - It’s a crucial step on the road to democracy.

(MacMillan Dictionary)